# How to use passport with jwt

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js, passport-local

I'm try to use passport with express, mongoose and jsonwebtoken, but got no response, when calling to /api. Please say what I'm missing.

```
index.js:
```

get passport and local strategy dependencies:

```
var passport = require("passport"),
    LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
```

configure passport:

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: "email"
},
  function (username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({email: username}, function (err, user) {
      if (err) return done(err);
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, {message: "User doesnt exist"});
      }
      if (!user.comparePassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, {message: "Wrong password!"});
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  })
);
```

and routes:

```
app.use("/api/login", require("./controllers/login"));
```

in my `./controllers/login.js`:

```
function loginHandler(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate("local", function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    ...
    var token = jwt.sign({name: user.email}, req.app.get("superSecret"),{expiresIn: 60000});    
    return res.json({token: token});
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So this is quite a bit late, but I just spent two days struggling with this issue. The problem is very simple and not at all obvious:

```
function loginHandler(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate("local", function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    ...
    var token = jwt.sign({name: user.email}, req.app.get("superSecret"),{expiresIn: 60000});    
    return res.json({token: token});
  })(req, res, next);
}
```

Note the `(req, res, next)` added to the end of the passport call. This is necessary. Without this, the `authenticate` function will not run.